# Parse string into JSON

Tags: velocity, template-engine

I have an array of objects `$arr` and an object has a property named as `jsonData` which contains json data in a string, how to parse that string to actual JSON object and retrieve lets say value for key `name`? I tried this:

```
#foreach ($obj in $arr)
    #set ($jsonData = "#evaluate(${obj.jsonData})")
    $jsonData.get("name")  ## <-- not working
#end
```

Answer (score 14):

If anyone using velocity in AWS API Gateway ends up here, you can use AWS'

**$util.parseJson()** to covert a string to JSON.

Make sure you note if your string is using single or double quotes. You may need to use $util.escapeJavaScipt.replaceAll() before parsing the string.

Comment: Apparently the API changed or some..Thanks to Nick for pointing it out. I edited my post to use 'util' not 'utils'.

Answer (score 6):

Fixed it like this:

```
#foreach ($obj in $arr)
    #set( $jsonData = '#set( $jsonData = ' + $obj.jsonData + ' )' )
    #evaluate ($jsonData)
    $jsonData.get("name")  ##<-- works now
#end
```

I was using `velocity 1.7`

Answer (score 0):

This is mainly AWS lambda (in **python**) response template related.. so.. if you want to return custom response code with json it is easy to return JSON in node js but when it comes to python as per i know, we cant raise dict as a value. So.. this may help. If you are doing like..

```
raise Exception({"responseCode": 400, "response": "missing :\"recipientCount\""})
```

It will throw exception in errorMessage key and value as a string.

To overcome this..

Add response code 400 in **Method Response**

regExp in **Integration Response** :

```
.*'responseCode': 400.*
```

Add Body Mapping Template as application/json:

```
$util.escapeJavaScript( $input.path('$.errorMessage')).replaceAll("\\'",'\"')
```

**Make sure you are not using single quotes in value in exception string.**

**Wrong**:

```
raise Exception({"responseCode": 400, "response": "missing :'recipientCount'"})
```

**Right**:

```
raise Exception({"responseCode": 400, "response": "missing :\"recipientCount\""})
```

**I know it is not best solution... but this is the only solution i have found. Feel free if you have better solution.**