# how to convert string to JSON in velocity

Tags: velocity

I have a stringified json which has a field exp_id:

> "{\"ps\":{\"sp_incl\":\"false\",\"sp_slab\":\"B\"}}"

the problem is it is a stringified JSON,But I need just JSON. Any idea how to convert it to json and not stringified JSON ?

And If anyone have the proper answer , mention the solution with code. $util.parseJson() is not working for me .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse string into JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41471260/parse-string-into-json)

Answer (score 0):

You can use $util.parseJson() to covert a string to JSON. Check this link [Parse string into JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41471260/parse-string-into-json).
Hope this helps.